# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXuE.png)

The program crashes once the user adds image, and username. Not sure what to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable `currentUser` is `String?`; an optional `String`, which means that the value it holds at runtime can be an actual string *or* `nil`. In order to use an optional value, you need to **unwrap** it. In the line where you're seeing the crash, you are forcing the unwrapping with `currentUser!`, which will crash if the value in `currentUser` was in fact `nil`.

Looking at line 21 in your screenshot, I'm guessing that the key `uid` doesn't exist in the Keychain at the time of running.

Comment: So because it may not recognize the uid, thats why its not being stored in firebase, and it crashes? How could fix it to where it doesn't it crash.

Comment: All I can say is that there isn't a value for the key `uid` in the keychain, hence `currentUser` is ending up `nil`. _Why_ is there not a `uid` entry in the keychain is not something I can answer here; it requires a deeper understanding of your app. But either way, I would recommend some defensive coding: what do you want your app to do when `uid` is not in the keychain? Be sure to handle that case. Because even if you put that key there yourself, it can get cleared by the user, or a system wipe, etc. It's not entirely under your control, so you can't assume it will always be there.

Comment: Weird thing is before I migrated the files over  to another program, it was working perfectly and storing the users, and messages to the database.